# Duplicates in the Path Variable Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, path

Is it safe to remove duplicates from the Path Variable ? The Path Variable of my Windows 7 OS looks like this:

```
1  C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
2  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
3  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
4  C:\windows\system32;
5  C:\windows;
6  C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
7  C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
8  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;
9  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
10 C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;
11 C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
12 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;
13 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
14 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
15 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;
16 %systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
17 C:\MySQL\bin;
18 %systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

There are some duplicates but i am not sure if i can just remove them. The lines 7,16 and 18 look identical to me, so can i just delete two of them or does `%systemroot%` and `C:\windows` make a difference ?  Also is it safe to remove line 2,3 and 9, because i do not use Windows Live ?

(Type `sysdm.cpl` in <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or (<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>)

Comment: I see only 1 dup. But you can always remove real dups.

Comment: @ott-- so there is difference between %systemroot% and c:\windows ? That means i can only delete the last line ?

Comment: The `%systemroot%` is evaluated at runtime and can be different from `c:\windows\ ` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting duplicates in the Path environment variable will not change anything. However,

> The %SystemRoot% variable is a special system-wide environment
>   variable found on Microsoft Windows NT and its derivatives. Its value
>   is the location of the system directory, including the drive and path.
>   The drive is the same as %SystemDrive% and the default path on a clean
>   installation depends upon the version of the operating system. By
>   default, Windows NT 5.1 (Windows XP) and newer versions use \WINDOWS,
>   Windows NT 5.0 (Windows 2000), Windows NT 4.0 and Windows NT 3.1 use
>   \WINNT, Windows NT 3.5x uses \WINNT35, and Windows NT 4.0 Terminal
>   Server uses \WTSRV

It should be safe to remove the [%systemroot%, C:\windows] duplicates if you are using windows XP or newer.

Comment: Thanks, so i can remove line 16 and 18, right?